# Calling column name inside function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function

Inside a function I have created, I have this loop that checks if the `id` is 0, if not check again with the new `id` as the `parent_id` from the last row.

```
until Category.find_by_id(id) == 0
        id = Category.parent_id
        i += i
end
```

With though, I get an error of `undefined method 'parent_id'`.  How do I call a column name correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent_id` is an instance method, not a class method. You need one of your instances to call it, and in this case, it appears you want to save the result of the `Category.find_by_id(id)` call to call `parent_id` on.

As a side note, you really want to be checking if `id` is `0`, because `Category.find_by_id(0)` will return `nil`, which will throw an error when compared with 0. Also, you should be able to use `find`, which defaults to looking up the `ID`

Comment: Comparision can throw an error, but you are right in this case. It won't throw an error (I was thinking of `>` and family)